# Aptana Studio 3 shows built-in functions as errors Python 2.7 PyDev

Tags: aptana, pydev

[image]I recently upgraded Aptana Studio and now the editor shows built-in functions as errors. I set the interpreter to Python 2.7 (C:\Python27\python.exe). I mean basic built-in functions like 'len', 'str', 'range' etc. ...

The code runs just fine when started from Aptana Studio, it just shows tons of errors in the editor. I have been using Aptana Studio for years now and I was always really happy with it.

Comment: I installed Eclipse. It works just fine with PyDev.